# Mongdb failed to get document from passing variable id

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I am using graphql resolver to get the relation document from database mongodb.

```
const resolvers = {
  User: {
    friends: async (parent, __, ctx) => {
      let friend = await ctx.db
         .collection("friends")
         .find({userID: "hardcodeID"})
         .toArray();  
      
     return friend; // work!
    }
  }
}
```

This will be Failed when i passing the id from the parent. I print it the parent._id. Yes, it return the value of the id. What cause this issue happened? i guess the parent._id is null when inside the find method. But, it is async await function, should got value ya?

```
 const resolvers = {
  User: {
    friends: async (parent, __, ctx) => {
      let friend = await ctx.db
         .collection("friends")
         .find({userID: parent._id})
         .toArray();  
      
     console.log(parent_.id) // someIdFromParent
     return friend; // []
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `.toString()` on `parent._id`. Looking at your example where
 `.find({userID: "hardcodeID"})` worked fine this suggested that in your `freinds` schema `userID` is speciecied as a `String` & your passing in, what looks like, an `ObjectID`.

```js
 const resolvers = {
  User: {
    friends: async (parent, __, ctx) => {
      let friend = await ctx.db
         .collection("friends")
         .find({userID: parent._id.toString()})
         .toArray();  
      
     return friend;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome :) @Wilker